# Show element only if getJSON takes more than n milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some JavaScript:

```
surveyBusy.show();

$.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        ...
        surveyBusy.hide();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        ...
        surveyBusy.hide();
    });
```

However, I'd like to only issue `surveyBusy.show();` if `$.getJSON` takes more than `n` number of milliseconds. You get a flicker otherwise. Is there a callback on the `getJSON` api that can do this? I see [nothing in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: I've just posted an answer that gives you the callback provided in the AJAX API to do this without additional code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a timeout. Also, I put your "hide" code in the `always` handler to reduce code repetition.

```
var busyTimeout = setTimeout(function() { surveyBusy.show(); }, 2000);

$.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        ...
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        ...
    })
    .always(function() {
        clearTimeout(busyTimeout);        
        surveyBusy.hide();        
    });
```

Comment: Best solution of the 4 proposed, almost identical ones

Comment: An improvement that I would suggest is to reference the `window` object when calling the methods `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. Apart from that, +1.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Why is that?

Comment: @Ian To indicate that the method you want to use is the one that's attached to the `window` object in case `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` are being redefined somewhere else in the global namespace, which may or may not be intentional.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 There's no reason to pollute your code with `window.` prefixes. Do you use `window.` everywhere? Are you using `window.document.whateverMethod`? Or for every global variable/function you create? I hope not, that's a little excessive for something that's implied. If it's being redefined somewhere else in the global namespace, there's no way to get around that - adding `window.` doesn't magically find the original...it's been overwritten already

Answer (score 4):

Put your `surveyBusy.show()` call inside a timeout and then cancel that timeout (using [window.clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout)) if the result is returned before it activates:

```
var busyTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() { surveyBusy.show(); }, 500);

$.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        ...
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        ...
    })
    .always(function() {
        window.clearTimeout(busyTimeout);        
        surveyBusy.hide();        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

```
var busy = window.setTimeout(function(){
    surveyBusy.show();
}, 1000);

$.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        // ...
        window.clearTimeout(busy);
        surveyBusy.hide();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        // ...
        window.clearTimeout(busy);
        surveyBusy.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting a timeout, then canceling it when the server responds:

```
// NOT TESTED

var n = 5000 // milliseconds
var tmr = setTimeout(function(){
    surveyBusy.show();
}, n);

$.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        ...
        clearTimeout(tmr) ;
        surveyBusy.hide();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        ...
        clearTimeout(tmr) ;
        surveyBusy.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set up a method within the surveyBusy object that will avoid having to create a `setTimeout` method under the window object. It gives you something a lot more reusable!!

```
surveyBusy = {
    onTimer: function(n) {
        elapsed = new Date.getTime() - start;
        if (elapsed > n) surveyBusy.show();
    }
}
surveyBusy.hide();
var start = new Date().getTime();
var elapsed = 0;

$.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        ...
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        ...
    })
    .always(function() {
        surveyBusy.onTimer(5000);
    });
```

Comment: I'll have to try it, but I'm pretty sure this won't work because `always` doesn't execute until **after** it gets a response.

Comment: @TheSolution Isn't that what the OP asked for? It must take at least "n" seconds or the `.show()` doesn't occur. Or have I misread it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to [this page, which describes the callbacks for all AJAX routines,](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) there is a timeout callback that you can use. It will require that you don't use the `$.getJSON` shortcut. So, to provide a REAL answer to the question, **YES it is in the API** but buried deeper than the `$.getJSON` shortcut.

> **timeout** Type: Number Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup().
>   The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if
>   several other requests are in progress and the browser has no
>   connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before
>   it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object
>   will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any
>   object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script
>   and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will
>   run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

Comment: Maybe show an example converting their `$.getJSON` call to `$.ajax` (which shouldn't be much), so they can utilize `timeout`

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure if the timeout is reached, the `fail` callbacks are executed, which probably isn't desired

Comment: "pretty sure" and "probably" sound like just a reason to attempt to invalidate my answer more than an educated comment.

Comment: And The Solution asked for an API-related answer, not a code snippet, which is exactly what I have provided.

Comment: Unfortunately, they asked about an API **callback**, so if you want to be technical, your answer is irrelevant. Like I said, if you bothered providing an example and testing it, you'd find its implications. Sorry I didn't care to test it myself, it's not my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
var n = 1000; //number of ms to wait
var done = false;
window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(!done){
        surveyBusy.show();
    }
}, n);

$.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        ...
        done = true;
        surveyBusy.hide();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        ...
                done = true;
        surveyBusy.hide();
    });
```