# Overriding global properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, global

After reading the [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147823/show-element-only-if-getjson-takes-more-than-n-milliseconds/18147896?noredirect=1#comment26581048_18147896) to my comment on the linked post, I decided to test things out with regards to the `window` object and global scope. I read some other questions regarding how to reference the original function such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original?lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert?lq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427708/override-function-e-g-alert-and-call-the-original-function?lq=1), but all of them generally involve storing the original in another variable or wrapping it in an anonymous function (separate namespace).

### Test code

```
var x = ' 0 '; // a global variable

document.body.innerHTML += x;
document.body.innerHTML += window.x;

// setTimeout before overriding
setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += ' 1 ';
}, 500);

// window.setTimeout before overriding
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += ' 2 ';
}, 1000);

// Overriding setTimeout
function setTimeout(f, time) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof f === 'function') {
        document.body.innerHTML += ' 3 ';
    }
}

// setTimeout after overriding
setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += ' 4 ';
}, 1000);

// window.setTimeout after overriding setTimeout globally
window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += ' 5 ';
}, 2000);

// Overriding window.setTimeout
window.setTimeout = function (f, time) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof f === 'function') {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    }
};

// window.setTimeout after overriding
window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += ' 6 ';
}, 3000);
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsTxt/1/). Note that after the fiddle initializes you may need to hit Run to see the delays.

### Experimental result

```
0
undefined
3
3
(page becomes orange) 
2 (after a delay)
5 (after a longer delay)
```

### Expected result

```
0
0
3
(page becomes orange)
1 (after 500ms)
2 (after 1000ms)
5 (after 2000ms)
```

Can anyone explain why my code's behaviour is different than expected?

Also, I realize that JavaScript run outside of a browser environment will differ, so for the purposes of this question I'll just stick to applications of JavaScript within a browser environment.

Comment: I'm famous! Haha I think that's cool that you actually took it out of the comments and made a question, instead of arguing it or just dismissing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in JSFiddle does not run in the global scope. That is why `window.x` is `undefined` after declaring and defining `x`.

As for the local scope redefinition. You are allowed to do this:

```
var a;
a = b();
function b() {
    return 5;
}
console.log(a); // 5
```

You are allowed to call b before it's declared and defined because it's moved to the top. This is also known as hoisting.

Even if you do this:

```
function b () {
    return 1;
}
(function () {
    console.log(b()); // 2, not 1
    function b() {
        return 2;
    }
}());
```

Again, because of hoisting. The actual execution order is:

```
var b;
b = function () {
    return 1;
}
(function () {
    var b;
    b = function b() {
        return 2;
    }
    console.log(b()); // 2, makes sense
}());
```